# Free agents every day at 9 AM In AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I am using using wait block for stopping agents moving to next block. I want them to get free every day at 9AM.

*My approach:* I tried to use **dynamic event**. what I did is when all the agents enter the wait I create dynamic event of 12 hours means after 12 hours the agents will be free. But that is not accurate approach.
[image]

I also tried **event** that have the option to occur at 9AM exact but it we can only select specific date of the month.

What I am trying to achieve is every day at 9AM the wait block free all the agents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using "schedule". For instance, in the schedule, you can use moments, assign the duration type as Days/weeks and repeat every day and specify the time as 09:00 AM. In the action bar use wait.freeAll() to free all the agents at 09:00 AM daily.

[image]

Comment: That is working fine but How agents get free at 9AM but leave the wait block over the period of 8 hours. Just like option intervals(Start, End) in the schedule.

Comment: if you want to keep the wait block open in an interval of 09:00 AM to 05:00 PM for example, you may use an event that checks the value of the schedule. You should use intervals in the schedule and create a cyclic event based on your model time unit and for each cycle check the status of the schedule and free the wait block by the following code:  if (schedule.getValue()) wait.freeAll(); here the wait block releases the agents in the interval of 09:00AM to 05:00PM for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a dynamic event. Just use a regular cyclic event:
[image]